# inserting values into hidden, and database problem?

Tags: jquery, mysql, html, css, hidden

i have this jquery code, which inserst the css property into a hidden input: here goes

```
$('#borderleft').val($('.leftpanel').css('border-left-width',"20px"));
```

and my hidden input field looks like:

```
 <input type="hidden" id="borderleft"name="borderleft"></input>
```

when i try to insert this input into the database, i get the value

```
[object Object]
```

instead of

```
20px
```

what is the problem, i dnt seem to understand thanks!!

Comment: There's no such thing as `</input>`, by the way. input fields are like `<br />`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you're running into here is that almost all of the jQuery methods return the instance of the object itself, so you can "chain" functions together. When you call:

```
$('.leftpanel').css('border-left-width',"20px")
```

The call to `css` actually returns the value of `$('.leftpanel')`, which is of course, an object.

Now, I gather you are intending to set the value of the hidden field to '20px', you can do so by the following:

```
var width = '20px';
$('.leftpanel').css('border-left-width',width)
$('#borderleft').val(width);
```

**Update**

If your intention is to simply get the current border width of the element, and set the value of your hidden field, you need to omit the second parameter to `css`, doing so will return you the current value. Your resulting code would be:

```
$('#borderleft').val($('.leftpanel').css('border-left-width'));
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i dnt think your solution is going to help me in what im trying to users are chnaging the appearance of a page, its not a constant value! im kind of stuck actually now

Comment: @getaway why? The `width` value isn't constant, you can make it assume whatever value you need

Comment: If you need to get the current value of the border, simply omit the second parameter, and it will return the value of the border on the element. So, your resulting code would just be:
`$('#borderleft').val($('.leftpanel').css('border-left-width'));`